# firebreath events window plugin mouse keyboard mac os

Tags: macos, firebreath

How do I connect to the ois library firebreath plugin in Mac OS?
I have pluginwindowmac, want to track mouse, keyboard, joystick.

made as to windows:

```
FB::MessageWindow* messageWindow = new FB::MessageWindow();
mParamList.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("WINDOW"), messageWindow->getHWND()));
mInputManager = OIS::InputManager::createInputSystem(mParamList);
```

messageWindow->getHWND() - no in mac os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any idea what the OIS library is expecting, but I can tell you that HWND is a windows type, so there will certainly never be a getHWND that works on mac os.

If what you need is a NSWindow then I'm afraid you're out of luck. The only way to get events in Mac OS in an NPAPI plugin is through the browser, which FireBreath exposes through its event system.

Comment: To get events from something like a joystick you'll need some way of getting them global, without a NSWindow or NSApplication.  I don't have any idea if that's possible or how to do it.

Comment: I try to get windowRef

pluginWindowMac-> getWindowRef ()

but I get NULL, when I draw core animation, core graphics should return WindowRef value but it is also empty. How do I get WindowRef window?

Comment: getWindowRef() only works with CoreGraphics during the duration of a draw event, which is the only time you're allowed to use it.  Use getDrawingPrimitive() to get the CALayer when you're using CoreAnimation. (it's a void*, cast it back to a CALayer*)

Comment: but what about the focus? event catches the browser only after clicking on the plug-in window

Comment: I dont' believe there is a way.

Comment: can you know. how to get windowref, the browser from a plugin? tried GetUserFocusWindow, CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo ... always equal to NULL

Comment: You can't.  You're in a different process.